# file_get_contents関数からslack通知を送りたい

Tags: php

【とりあえず解決】
コマンドラインから叩くとテストサーバーのOS、opensllのバージョンが低いので出来ないという事でした。
本番で試して今は問題なく動いています。
いろいろと教えていただきありがとうございました。
解決はどこを押せばいいのかわかりませんのでこちらに記載しました。

---

ブラウザ(chrome)からphpを叩くhttp通信だとslack通知は届くのですが
teratermのコマンドラインでphp動かすと下のエラーが出ました。

OSバージョンは

```
CentOS release 5.〇 (Final)
OpenSSL 0.9.8e・・・ 2008
```

です。

file_get_contents のオプションには

```
$options = array(
'http' => array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'header' => 'Content-Type: application/json',
    'content' => json_encode($message),
)
,
'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer'      => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false
)
);
```

これをfile_get_contentsの第3引数に入れています。

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version in /usr・・・
```

とエラーが出てしまいました。なぜなんでしょうか？

Comment: 解決した場合には質問に追記するのではなく、[役に立った回答を承認してください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) 。過去にも何度か実施されているはずです。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージで検索すれば分かるかと思いますが、OpenSSLライブラリのバージョンが古いのが原因かと思われます。

現状の環境を維持するなら OpenSSL をソースコードからコンパイルして新しいバージョンをインストールすることも可能かと思いますが、CentOS 5 は 2017年にサポート切れとなっているので、OS 自体の更新を検討したほうが良さそうです。

Comment: opensslやcent os 5が古いからなんですね。php5.2で動くのはphpのsslから通信しているからなんでしょうか？

Comment: phpがどのopensslを使用しているかわかりませんが、1.0・・・でテストサーバーのopensslは0.9・・・なのでそこを変更すればエラーがなくなるのかな、おっしゃる通りlinuxのopensslを上げれば改善しそうだなと思いました。ありがとうございました。